# Cannot animate a view that is off screen

Tags: android

I am animating a view that is off screen with `.animate()`, but this view will not animate if it is not at least partially on screen. The view should slide up over the entire screen from the bottom.

**For example:**

If I set the Y-offset to 615 dp which is exactly the height of the visible screen, the view will not animate.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/purple_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0FF0"
    android:layout_y="615"/>
```

However, if the view is partilaly visible on screen, even just by 1 dp for example, it will animate

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/purple_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0FF0"
    android:layout_y="614"/>
```

Now why is this may I ask? Here is the entire layout file

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/white_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFF0"
        android:layout_y="0dp"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/purple_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0FF0"
        android:layout_y=""
        />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```